# powershell on target machine causes "PSSession could not be created for Machine:'XXX:5986"

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, powershell-remoting

I try to use release pipeline and setup a task "run powershell on target machines"

And here are the error messages:

```
##[error]Unable to create pssession. Error: 'Connecting to remote server XXX failed with the following error message : The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig". For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.'

##[error]The remote session query failed for XXX with the following error message: The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig". 

##[error]PSSession could not be created for Machine:'XXX:5986'
```

My VM is on Azure, and I already open PORT 5986\5985 in 'internet' settings.
I found some article talking about "remote management", however, I am not sure how to set this up on my VM.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrm/portal
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/winrmsecurity?view=powershell-7.2

Maybe I need some setup are needed for the instance which pipelines are running on (agent pools)?
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/with-powershell-on-target-machines-task-cant-able/635225

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Update-1
[image]
[image]

The suggestion from @wade-zhou-msft seems not working. But thanks!

Updata-2
[image]
change the network setting, no more error.
But the situation still the same ...

In addition, my 'copy file to remote machine' task works well.

Update-3
I find articles talks about "how to remotely run powershell command from Linux"
https://adamtheautomator.com/psremoting-linux/
It shows that some setup is needed. Maybe I need to setup the instance running my CD jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task "run powershell on target machines" will start a `Enter-PSSession` session from `your agent machine` to `target VM`.

As per the error message, on your target VM, please run `winrm quickconfig` to configure the service, run `winrm set winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="*"}'` to trust the host.

If you use the HTTPS, then you need to open port 5986 in the firewall and install a self-signed certificate.

If you create a classic virtual machine from the Azure portal,the virtual machine is already set up for WinRM over HTTPS, with the default port 5986 already opened in the firewall and a self-signed certificate installed on the machine.These virtual machines can be accessed with no further configuration required. Please refer to the [task perquisite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines?view=azure-devops#prerequisites) for the detials.

Or you can use self-hosted agent, with http port 5985 for the task.

[image]

Comment: I run "winrm quickconfig" and received 【Error number:  -2144108183 0x80338169
WinRM firewall exception will not work since one of the network connection types on this machine is set to Public. Chang
e the network connection type to either Domain or Private and try again.
PS C:\Users\dsu_user>】   Did I miss something?

Comment: Besides, my "copy file to Windows machine" task works fine

Comment: Hi @hanshih, if the network connection type is set to Public, the `winrm quickconfig` could be failed as  PowerShell expects domain or private connection types. Please go to control panel on target VM, check the network type, switch to private or domain type. You can refer to link for the detials: https://4sysops.com/archives/enabling-powershell-remoting-fails-due-to-public-network-connection-type/#changing-the-network-connection-type-with-powershell

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I update the setting, and error resolves. But it did not solve my problem...

Comment: Hi @hanshih, as per the new screenshot, winrm listens on "Http" not "Https". 
Is your target VM domain joined? Do you install self-signed certificate on it? And you can also give a try with "Http" with 5985 for a try.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Changing from 'https' to 'http' solve my problem!

Comment: Glad to know it works! Could you please mark it as answer so that it can help others who has same queries?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved the problem by using azure cli.
The build agent and the VM were added in the same vNet.

```
az vm run-command invoke -g MyResourceGroup -n MyVm --command-id RunShellScript --scripts 'echo $1 $2' --parameters hello world
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/run-command?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-run-command-invoke